# Need help on how to pass AWS signature while hitting API endpoint in Karate

Tags: karate, aws-signature

Need help on how to pass AWS signature while hitting API endpoint in Karate.

Currently , i am unable to pass AWS signature in Karate Test automation . Could you share any insights on how to handle it in Karate APU automation

Need help on how to pass AWS signature while hitting API endpoint in Karate.